# Can I refer another aggregate root in child entity?

Tags: domain-driven-design

I am modelling user management domain where I have to address domain activities such as registration, login, role management etc.. I have come up with below aggregates.

When user registration is approved, I have to add an entry into users table and then persist his roles

`Users <<root>> ----> User Roles (child entity)`

New roles can be created by choosing appropriate privileges

`Roles <<root>> ----> Role Privileges (child entity)`

Privilege master table

`Privileges <<root>>`

My questions is, in the User Roles (child entity) of Users aggregate, can I have role_id which links to Roles aggregate root?

If I have to persist user roles, the business invariant is to make sure the roles are valid roles and hence I have to validate role_id against role master. So in the same transaction, can read data from another aggregate? Please note that, these aggregates are in the same microservice.

Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

Define "links".

It's perfectly OK for an aggregate to refer/link to another aggregate root by a stable identifier (e.g. a string ID).  You can then use that ID to request another aggregate (e.g. from a repository).  With that other aggregate you can perform reads, but should never perform updates.

Remember that aggregates define consistency and transactional boundaries.  The aggregate you get need not be the latest version of that aggregate: it's a version of that aggregate from some point before you requested it (hopefully it's the latest version as of when you requested it, but that might not always be the case) and it cannot reflect changes since you requested it.

However, if your reference/link is through something more direct, then those consistency/transactional boundaries are violated, so that's generally not allowed (or at least not a good idea, as you're giving up other benefits of DDD).